# django project not working in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I recently installed a virtualenv and cloned an existing django project into it. When I run `python manage.py runserver` I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/user/eb-virt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 95, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'application-name.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named application-name.settings
```

when I try doing `application-name/application python manage.py runserver`, I get the following error:

`python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

here is the application directory

```
application-name/
    manage.py
    application/
       __init__.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
       settings.py
```

Comment: Assuming that `application-name`  is not the name of your app (because then that's your problem)? The current directly contains `application-name/settings.py`?

Comment: that may be part of the problem. the original django application is named 'application'. when i cloned it into the virtualenv, i named it 'application-name'. so should i change it application-name/application/settings.py?

Comment: I've tried changing the path multiple times, but have not had any luck

Comment: Depends on where `settings.py` is located. And of course `application-name` is not a valid python identifier. While `importlib` seems to handle such names, I'm not so sure about the remainder of the ecosystem.

Comment: @PCR, Did you activate your virtualenv before running `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: yes i did activate it @TitanFighter

Comment: @dhke settings.py is located in application-name/application. manage.py is located in application-name

Comment: @dhke i added the project directory

Comment: Edit `manage.py` and replace `application-name.settings` with `application.settings`. Also make sure the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is not set to `application-name.settings`

Answer (score 0):

First, rename your `application-name` to `application_name`. Dashes and Python source is just inviting problems, best not wake the dragons.

Let's assume you've put it in `~/work/application_name`, i.e. outside your virtualenv.

If you didn't create the virtualenv with `virtualenvwrapper` and it doesn't have a `setup.py` file, then delete it (and install `virtualenvwrapper`).

Create your virtualenv with `virtualenvwrapper`:

```
mkvirtualenv -a ~/work/application_name -r ~/work/application_name/requirements.txt eb_virt
```

`-a` add an existing directory as a project dir (puts it on the python path for this virtualenv). `-r` runs `pip install -r` on the argument (I'm assuming `application_name/requirements.txt` exists).

Instead of using the `-a` option (and assuming `application_name/setup.py` exists), you can install your package in development mode :

```
cd ~/work
pip install -e application_name
```

Either of these make ~/work/application_name part of the module search path when Python is running.  Your settings file path must start relative to a directory on Python's module search path.

The  `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable, should therefore be set to `'application.settings'`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. How do I delete the virtualenv?

Comment: You just delete it from your file system, assuming you haven't created any files there that you want to save (you really shouldn't create anything there yourself). Virtualenvwrapper comes with a rmvirtualenv command (and many more conveniences for working with virtuakenvs).